# Usage of Xilinx built-in UART function #define XUartPs_IsReceiveData (BaseAddress )

Tags: c, uart, xilinx

So I am trying to use this built-in UART function (from the Vitis SDK from Xilinix) to determine if there is a valid byte to read over UART. I created this function to return 1 if there was a byte to read or 0 if there wasn't

```
u32 UartHasMessage(void){
if(XUartPs_IsReceiveData(&XUartPs_Main)){
    return 1;
}
else{
    return 0;
}
}
```

However, even when there is a byte to read over UART, this function always returns false.
The weird behavior I am experiencing is when I step through the code using the debugger, I call UartHasMessage() to check if there is a byte to read, and it returns false, but in the next line I call a function to read a byte over UART and that contains the correct byte I sent over the host.

[image]

```
u32 test - UartHasMessage();
UartGetByte(&HostReply);
```

How come this UartHasMessage always returns false, but then in the next line I am able to read the byte correctly?

Comment: What is `XUartPs_Main`? Without a definition for that, this is just a guess ... Based on the macro it's passed to, I assume it is/should be a base address. So, maybe you should change: `XUartPs_IsReceiveData(&XUartPs_Main)` into: `XUartPs_IsReceiveData(XUartPs_Main)`

Comment: @CraigEstey Hey Craig, its the base address. I am using a few other Uart functions and I pass in the base address with &XUartPs_Main and they all work as expected. I am only having issues with this function in particular

Comment: "*this built in UART function*" -- Built-in to what software package?

Comment: @sawdust Built into the Vitis SDK from Xilinix

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat:* Without some more information, this is a bit speculative and might be a comment, but it is too large for that.

The information below comes from the Xilinx documentation on various pages ...

---

`XUartPs_RecvByte` will *block* until a byte is ready. So, no need to call `XUartPs_IsReceiveData` directly (I *think* that `XUartPS_RecvByte` calls it internally).

---

A web search on `XUartPs_Main` came up with nothing, so we'd need to see the definition you have.

Most Xilinx documentation uses `UART_BASEADDRESS`:

```
#define UART_BASEADDR XPAR_XUARTPS_0_BASEADDR
```

I found a definition:

```
#define XPAR_XUARTPS_0_BASEADDR 0xE0001000
```

You might be better off using a more standard method, such as calling the `XUartPs_LookupConfig` function to get the configuration table entry which has all relevant values.

---

I'm guessing that *you* created the `XUartPS_Main` definition.

But, based on what you posted, (needing `&XUartPS_Main` instead of `XUartPS_Main`), it is linked/loaded at the exact address of the UART register bank. Let's assume that address is (e.g.) 0x10000. So, we might have:

```
u32 XUartPS_Main __attribute__(at(0x10000));
```

The `at` is an extension that some build systems support (e.g. arm) that forces the variable to be loaded at a given address. So, let's assume we have that (even if the mechanism is slightly different (e.g.):

```
__attribute__((section(".ARM.__at_0x10000")))
```

---

The definition of `XUARTPS_SR_OFFSET` is:

```
#define XUARTPS_SR_OFFSET   0x002CU
```

Offsets are [typically] *byte* offsets.

Given:

```
#define XUartPs_IsReceiveData(BaseAddress)  \
!((Xil_In32((BaseAddress) + XUARTPS_SR_OFFSET) &        \
        (u32)XUARTPS_SR_RXEMPTY) == (u32)XUARTPS_SR_RXEMPTY)
```

Now *if* the definition of `XUartPS_Main` uses `u32` [as above], we may have a problem because `XUARTPS_SR_OFFSET` will be treated as a `u32` *index* and *not* a byte offset. So, it will access the *wrong* address.

So, try:

```
XUartPs_IsReceiveData((unsigned char *) &XUartPs_Main)
```

But, if it were me, I'd rework things to use Xilinx's standard definitions.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Hi so `XUartPs_main` is defined as `static XUartPs XUartPs_Main;` I use it in a variety of functions such as a function to send bytes over uart and I call it by its address like I did with this function, all my other functions work as expected except this one. Is it possible it is something to do with the way the fifo works? –
> 29belgrade29

No, not all the API functions are the same.

The `struct` definition is [I synthesized this from the API doc]:

```
typedef struct {
    u16     DeviceId;                   // Unique ID of device.
    u32     BaseAddress;                // Base address of device (IPIF)
    u32     InputClockHz;
} XUartPs;
```

Somewhere in your code you had to *initialize* this with:

```
XUartPs_Main = XUartPs_ConfigTable[my_device_id];
```

Or, with:

```
XUartPs_Main = *XUartPs_LookupConfig(my_device_id);
```

*If* an API function is defined as (e.g.):

```
void api_dosomething(XUartPs_Config *cfg,...)
```

Then, you call it with:

```
api_dosomething(&XUartPs_Main,...);
```

So, most functions probably take such a pointer.

But, `XUartPs_IsReceiveData` does *not* want a pointer to a `XUartPs_Config` struct. It wants a *base address*. This is:

```
XUartPs_Main.BaseAddress
```

So, you want:

```
XUartPs_IsReceiveData(XUartPs_Main.BaseAddress)
```

Comment: Hi so XUartPs_main is defined as `static XUartPs XUartPs_Main;` I use it in a variety of functions such as a function to send bytes over uart and I call it by its address like I did with this function, all my other functions work as expected except this one. Is it possible it is something to do with the way the fifo works?

Comment: I tried your fix, and now I have the opposite problem, the function always returns 1 now even if I didnt send a byte. It could be returning 1 because it is reading the last send byte that has already been read. In this case with your change it returns 1 but when it goes to read the byte from Uart there is nothing to read

Comment: Ok thank you, the update to your post helped a lot, but my question still remains the function always returns 1 now even if didn't sent a byte over UART. Is it possible it is still looking at the previously sent byte over UART? Does the byte clear after its been read? Essentially my code starts when it receives the go command over UART and loops until it receives the stop command, since XUartPs_IsReceiveData(XUartPs_Main.BaseAddress) is still returning 1 even when I didn't send the stop command is it possible that is still "looking" at the go command i sent over UART in the FIFO?

Comment: @29belgrade29 Just curious: Is `u32 test - UartHasMessage();` really your code? Looks like a syntax error to me. I think you really need to post _more_ [most(?)] of your code to be able to see the context. What is the device on the other end of the line (datasheet?)? Which Xilinx chip (and config)? Can you put a scope on the line to see if spurious chars are sent. Or, there may be stale chars in the FIFO from a prior run (depending upon init sequence). You may wish to _disassemble_ `XUartPS_RecvByte` to see what is does [extra] to service the device.